# DIV Overflow Scroll Stopping Short

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow

I'm trying to make a DIV for a chat box scroll when overflowed, but unfortunately it's stopping short and I don't know why. Here is my code.

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it? Right now what happens is that it will scroll down for a little while, but then it will stop scrolling. I've been stuck on this problem for almost an hour now.

Comment: when does it stop scrolling? how many lines down?

Comment: Your code doesn't help us I'm afrad: http://jsfiddle.net/rF4rn/

Comment: I have the chat app hosted on my server now at goo.gl/QBYfS with Dave Thomas's suggestion. But now it's not scrolling at all although it works fine in JSFiddle. Can you guys take a look at it and find out why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not, currently, sure why your own attempt fails (though I'd guess it's a problem with the variable `CHATBOX_ID`, but that's only because you've not shown where it's coming from), this version works. Albeit with a couple of assumptions (which I'll explain later):

```
var chatContentHeight, scrollVal;
var chatHeight = $('#chat').height();

$('#message').keyup(

function(e) {
    chatContentHeight = 0;
    if (e.keyCode == '13') { // assuming you want messages submitted on hitting 'enter'
        newMsg = $(this).val();
        $('<div />').text(newMsg).appendTo('#chat');
        $(this).val('');

        $('#chat > div').each(

        function() {
            chatContentHeight = chatContentHeight + $(this).outerHeight();
        });

        if (chatContentHeight > chatHeight) { // checking whether or not scrolling is needed
            scrollVal = (chatContentHeight - chatHeight); // defines the amount to scroll
            $('#chat').scrollTop(scrollVal);
        }
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JrZNU/1/).

My assumptions are:

1. that you *want* messages submitted on hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>,
2. that you'll be okay/want to use `div`s to contain the messages, I'd personally prefer to use a `dl` or `ol`, but it seemed to complicate the demo a little to use those elements, though they're perfectly possible to use.

If you'd like an explanation (or, at least, if you'd like to help us to be able to *offer* an explanation) you'll need to at least post your full jQuery/JavaScript or link to a live demo that reproduces your problem (either on your own server or at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar).

References:

- [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

Comment: Also the strange thing is that it works fine on JSFiddle but not on my server with the full HTML code. The CSS code is about the same though as is the JS. I figure it must be a problem with the HTML structure, possibly with browser height limits on absolutely positioned divs.

Comment: I'll have a look for you, sure; but probably not until tomorrow afternoon/evening, I'm afraid. Sorry, but I'll try my best to help out some more.